# Doubts on a proof regarding the non-regularity of cusp's support

Tags: differential-geometry, proof-explanation

In the first place, let's define a few things. We call "support" of a curve $\gamma:I\rightarrow R^3;I\subseteq R$ the image of $I$ trough $\gamma$, $\gamma(I)$. We say that a curve $\gamma:I\rightarrow R^3;I\subseteq R$ is "regular" if its velocity, $\gamma'(u)$, is non-zero $\forall u\in I$. Now, let $\gamma:R\rightarrow R^3;u\mapsto(u^2,u^3,0)$ be a parametrization of the cusp. It's simple to prove that $\gamma'(u)=(2u,3u^2,0)=0\iff u=0$ and this implies that the cusp in not a regular curve. I then read the following lemma: "the support of the cusp is not regular". The proof goes like that: let $\alpha:I\rightarrow R^3;I\subseteq R;u\mapsto (\alpha_1(u),\alpha_2(u),0)$ be any parametrization of cusp's support and let $t_0\in I$ be such that $\alpha(t_0)=(0,0,0)$; we want to show that $\alpha'(t_0)=0$ and so that $\alpha$ is not regular exactly in $t_0$. We have that $\alpha_1(u)\ge0$ $\forall u\in I$ so it follows that $t_0$ is a minimum point for $\alpha_1\rightarrow \alpha_1'(t_0)=0$. Now there can be two cases: a]$\alpha_2(u)=0$ in a neighborhood of $t_0\rightarrow \alpha_2'(t_0)=0$; b]$\alpha_2(u)\ne0$ in a neighborhood of $t_0$, then there exists a sequence $[t_n]$ such that $t_n\rightarrow t_0$ and $\alpha_2(t_n)>0$ $\forall n\in N$. By definition of the cusp we have: $\alpha_2(t_n)=\alpha_1(t_n)^{\frac{3}{2}}$ which gives us $\alpha_2(t_0)=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\alpha_2(t_n)-\alpha_2(t_0)}{t-t_0}=0$. My questions on this proof are: a]how we went from $\gamma:R\rightarrow R^3;u\mapsto(u^2,u^3,0)$ as "the cusp" to a general $\alpha:I\subseteq R\rightarrow R^3;u\mapsto (\alpha_1(u),\alpha_2(u),0)$ as "the cusp", or, stated differently: is it sufficient that $\alpha_2(u)=\alpha_1(u)^{\frac{3}{2}}$ to define a cusp in this case ? b]why if $\alpha_2(u)\ne0$ in a neighborhood of $t_0$ then we can find a sequence $[t_n]$ such that $t_n\rightarrow t_0$ and $\alpha_2(t_n)>0$ $\forall n\in N$ ?